# Product doesn't appear in front office - Error in CategoryController.php - Prestashop 1.6.0.9

Tags: php, prestashop, product

I have an issue with my shop. 
When i add a new product in the back office. Everything seems to work perfectly (duplicate or create new product), however when I click to preview the product that i just added, I'm redirected on the index. And if go to the category where i put the new product, he doesn't appear.

To have a clue i checked the error.log file and put my DEV_MOD to true, it gave me this :

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/.../public_html/controllers/front/CategoryController.php on line 212

I really don't know how to fixed this, and need help,
Thanks.

Comment: Try updating prestashop

Comment: I'm already at 1.6.0.9 version and the latest is 1.6.0.11 but i'll give it a try

Answer (score 0):

I found out what it was, in override/class, Product.php, Category.php and ProductSale.php were making my site bugging.

I just deleted them from the ftp and now it works but only for showing the product in their categories and modules like "New products", "Best sales".

My last problem is when i click on those products to command. I get redirected on the index. The really weird thing is that on my test site, i have exactly the same files on the ftp and the same DB but all works great.